# Linux server - AD Login enabled - how to add AD group to local group

Tags: linux, ldap, active-directory, sssd

My RHEL servers are enabled with Active Directory authentication configured in sssd.conf

I have allowed few AD groups in sssd.conf to login to the Linux server.

the issue is I need to know how do I add this AD groups members in local group membership. I tired adding the AD group in /etc/group but thats not working

```
docker:x:332:user1,user2,**g-my-AD-user-group**
```

Comment: `/etc/group` does not support nested groups

Comment: thanks @AndrewLowther, any other workaround to achieve this please ?